# Generate Rotating Average

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

My requirements are to add a line to the chart below which represents averages per 8 weeks, which will be used multiple time throughout the report.  At this point I am pulling out my hair tying to figure this one out.  So far I have been using a temp table, looping through 8 weeks of data at a time, calculating the averages based on those 8 weeks, insert those values into a lut, joining the table in my proc, and then dishing the report out via SSRS.  Its not very maintainable, alot of ugly code, and I am sure there are some performance hits along the way, though not my biggest concern.

Below is some sample data:

```
region     yearnbr    weeknbr     value
A          2014       1           32
A          2014       2           77
A          2014       3           102
A          2014       4           84
A          2014       5           90
A          2014       6           90
A          2014       7           79
A          2014       8           103
A          2014       9           107
A          2014       10          110
A          2014       11          85
A          2014       12          120
A          2014       13          83
A          2014       14          79
A          2014       15          91
A          2014       16          101
A          2014       17          102
A          2014       18          103
A          2014       19          106
A          2014       20          95

...
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is add another field which would account for the averages on a 8 week rotation for each region, then use that field in the SSRS chart to generate an average with their respected values.  Below is an example of what I am after.  If there is a better solution, I would love to hear it...  In this example, lets just assume we are on week 20.

```
region     yearnbr    weeknbr     value     average
A          2014       1           32         82
A          2014       2           77         82
A          2014       3           102        82
A          2014       4           84         82
A          2014       5           90         82
A          2014       6           90         82
A          2014       7           79         82
A          2014       8           103        82
A          2014       9           107        97
A          2014       10          110        97
A          2014       11          85         97
A          2014       12          120        97
A          2014       13          83         97
A          2014       14          79         97
A          2014       15          91         97
A          2014       16          101        97
A          2014       17          102        102
A          2014       18          103        102
A          2014       19          106        102
A          2014       20          95         102

...
```

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks.

Details:
SQL Server 2008 R2 
SSRS

Comment: Is there a reason you have `yearnbr` and `weeknbr` instead of dates? How are you calculating week numbers? Can you put a date representing the first of the week into the rowset (or is such a value available in the underlying query)? The reason I'm asking is because the solution becomes much harder when `weeknbr` can in some years be 53 and in other years be 52.

Comment: There is an underlining data-mart which is where this data is derived from. I could put the date value in, not a problem. What's your suggestion?

Comment: Ooh, that makes it easier, you can ignore the parts of my query where I calculate a date.

Comment: Where does the term "rotating average" come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's this simple in SQL Server 2005 and up:

```
SELECT
   D.*,
   Average8weeks =
      Avg(D.value * 1.0) -- multiply by 1.0 if you don't want only integers
      OVER (PARTITION BY D.region, D.yearnbr, (D.weeknbr - 1) / 8)
FROM
   #Data D -- or whatever your table or query is
;
```

If you're using SQL Server 2000 or earlier, please let me know.

Here's setup script for sample data to try this out:

```
SELECT *
INTO #Data
FROM
   (VALUES
      ('A', 2014, 1, 15),
      ('A', 2014, 2, 30),
      ('A', 2014, 3, 25),
      ('A', 2014, 4, 45),
      ('A', 2014, 5, 15),
      ('A', 2014, 6, 30),
      ('A', 2014, 7, 25),
      ('A', 2014, 8, 45),
      ('A', 2014, 9, 10),
      ('A', 2014, 10, 54),
      ('B', 2014, 1, 63),
      ('B', 2014, 2, 10),
      ('B', 2014, 3, 54),
      ('B', 2014, 4, 63),
      ('B', 2014, 5, 54),
      ('B', 2014, 6, 63),
      ('B', 2014, 7, 54),
      ('B', 2014, 8, 63),
      ('B', 2014, 9, 54),
      ('B', 2014, 10, 63)
   ) D (region, yearnbr, weeknbr, value)
;
```

Comment: This is perfect!  Simple and clean.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, your output would show plot two line graphs on the same Y-axis, one with weekly data, the other a step function where for the first 8 weeks the value is the avg of weeks 1-8, and so on, correct?

If that is the case, then create a second set of records for the second series, and combine both series into one data set, then plot them in SSRS as a line graph with two series sharing the same axis.

Comment: You are correct, as the average is based on 8 week increments.  I'll look into this and give it a try tomorrow.  Thanks.

Comment: That works, but I would have to do this for each region, which is what is holding me back.  Lets say I had 30 regions, how could I write a query that would find the specified average for all 30 and store them in another table.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to get the result set returning the average of 8 values in one set, below code will get you the desired result:

```
;WITH CTE AS (

 SELECT * FROM
   (VALUES
      ('A', 2014, 1, 32.00),
      ('A', 2014, 2, 77.00),
      ('A', 2014, 3, 102.00),
      ('A', 2014, 4, 84.00),
      ('A', 2014, 5, 90.00),
      ('A', 2014, 6, 90.00),
      ('A', 2014, 7, 79.00),
      ('A', 2014, 8, 103.00),
      ('A', 2014, 9, 107.00),
      ('A', 2014, 10, 110.00),
      ('A', 2014, 11, 85.00),
      ('A', 2014, 12, 120.00),
      ('A', 2014, 13, 83.00),
      ('A', 2014, 14, 79.00),
      ('A', 2014, 15, 91.00),
      ('A', 2014, 16, 101.00),
      ('A', 2014, 17, 102.00),
      ('A', 2014, 18, 103.00),
      ('A', 2014, 19, 106.00),
      ('A', 2014, 20, 95.00)
   ) D (region, yearnbr, weeknbr, value))

 SELECT Region, yearnbr, (weeknbr-1)/8+1 Week, CAST(SUM(value)/8 AS FLOAT) AVG FROM CTE
 GROUP BY Region, yearnbr, (weeknbr-1)/8
```

Please correct me if I have misunderstood your requirement.